# Dell Optiplex 380 RAM upgrade

Tags: memory, ddr3, dell-optiplex

I own an optiplex 380 which currently has 2x2GB DDR3 RAM, now I am willing to upgrade to 8GB and I tested a Kingston ValueRam of 4GB @ 1333Mhz and my system beeped with 1 and 3 LED lights lit. So does it means 1333mhz is too high? Should I try to find a 1067mhz one?

Comment: What is the frequency of the memory that came with the system?

Comment: You cannot upgrade to 8GB.  You cannot even upgrade to 6GB.  Your system only supports 4GB.  You also cannot use any module larger then 2GB in capacity otherwise your system will not boot.  *If the capacity  of the module was 2GB then the memory module you purchased would have worked.*

Comment: [Its a chipset limitation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/mainstream-chipsets/g41-express-chipset.html) 4gb for DDR3 or 8GB for DDR2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

late answer however would help next users. Maximum ram is 8GB. Any frequency would be supported but RAM will run at the chipset's speed that is to say 1067Mhz, no more. Problem with your ram comes with the modules density. 
Funny that people assert that 4gb is the max. I have here on my left knee an optiplex 380 running with 2x4gb of 1600mhz crucial ballistix sports, running at 1067mhz.

Answer (score 6):

Judging by the [Manual](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-380_Service%20Manual_en-us.pdf) I would say that your RAM is not compatible.

Look at this:
[image]

**Maximum memory: 4GB @ 1067 MHz**.
That means that each RAM module bank can support a maximum of 2GB. So 2x2GB @ 1067 MHz is the best you can get with this board.
If you look at page 12/13 you can see the explanation of the error code

Comment: And 4GB is the total memory limit, single bank limit is 2GB.

Comment: Yes. Good catch, I will add that. Wasn't clear enough, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Their seems to be some conflicting information with the dell manuals:
check out the max memory from the dell optiples 380 setup and Features Information pdf - http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-380_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf

Memory module connector 2 DIMM slots
Memory module capacity 1 GB, 2 GB, or 4 GB 
Memory type 1067 MHz DDR3
Minimum memory 1 GB
Maximum memory 8 GB

and 
from Dell™ OptiPlex™ 380 Service Manual—Mini-Tower

http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-380_service%20manual2_en-us.pdf

Memory Connectors two
Capacity 1 GB or 2 GB
Type DDR3 SDRAM (non-ECC memory only) 1067 MHz
Minimum memory 1 GB
Maximum memory 4 GB

bottom line is that the memory must low density (chips on both sides of the dimm), non-ecc, 1067 mhz (pc3-8500). Where these manuals differ is that one list max memory as 8gb and the other 4gb.

Comment: I believe this is correct. When Dell published the manual, possibly 4 GB modules were not available, were thus not tested, and therefor not mentioned. The problem will most likely be that those he bought are not low-density. They are typically more expensive. I made the mistake with my Optiplex 755 as well (though DDR2).

Comment: I too made the high density mistake with my optiplex 380. Luckily the company I bought from is willing to do a flat exchange for low density.